# Jax-ws customize generated WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I need to change the JAX-WS generat WSDL  because of a soap:address error (contextRoot it is not correct due to a WebService remapping of the Application Server).
I Read about the WSDLGeneratorExtension system but I can not use it, i placed a com.sun.xml.ws.api.wsdl.writer.WSDLGeneratorExtension file under /META-INF/services with insite de class name of my implementation, but it is never called.

How can i let it work? Or Can i follow another way to corret the soap:address location of the generated WSDL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usual practice is not to use (or even include) actual service URL into WSDL (unless it's some sort of public service which is supposed to be 'well known'). Reasons being that different environments running the same service would have different URLs, for example.

As part of WS client initialization you could provide different URL (usually from some sort of config file). So you perhaps should not think in terms of fixing URL in WSDL but instead pass proper URL in your client initialization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... the problem is that JAX-WS automatically generate that WSDL with the soap:address. And I don't know how to prevent it.